# Get number between two characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, text-extraction

I am trying to find the number between two underscores (_) in strings like these:

```
234534_45_92374
3433_9458_034857
zx_8458_047346daf
```

What would be the regex for this?

Comment: A good resource to learn it: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
preg_match('/_(\d+)_/', $str, $matches);
$number = (int) $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your sample strings appear consistently formatted, you do not need to include the validation of matching the trailing underscore.

With `preg_match()`, match the literal underscore, then forget that you matched it (using `\K`), then match one or more digits.  The match will be a string -- if you need an integer type, then cast the string to an `int`.

If you definitely want the number to be cast as an integer, PHP offers a more direct function: `sscanf()`. Silently consume the one or more non-underscore characters, then the underscore, then capture the one or more digit number and use `%d` to dictate that the value must be an `int` type variable.

Codes: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ikO3Q))

```
preg_match('/_\K\d+/', $test, $match);
var_export($match[0]);
```

Or

```
sscanf($test, '%*[^_]_%d', $integer);
var_export($integer);
```