# regex preg_match for digit in middle for a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
ddw_0_op1
ddw_1_op1
ddw_2_op1
ddw_3_op1
ddw_4_op1
```

in these strings of array how i can extract or preg_match only the number in middle that increase . thanks in advance

Comment: Try `(?<=_)\d+(?=_)` or `_\K\d+(?=_)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex for number between two underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670774/regex-for-number-between-two-underscores)

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would break the string on underscore:

```
$parts = explode('_', $string);
$middle = $parts[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number never exceeds a single digit, you could simply use `$str[4]` to get the fifth character of the string (your digit). On the other hand, however, if the numbers continue indefinitely, you could use either of the following regular expressions.

#### Option 1

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/kHzV2X/1)

```
(?<=_)\d+(?=_)
```

- `(?<=_)` Positive lookbehind asserting what precedes is `_`
- `\d+` Matches one or more digits
- `(?=_)` Positive lookahead asserting what follows is `_`

#### Option 2

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/kHzV2X/2): This method uses fewer steps than the previous.

```
_\K\d+(?=_)
```

- `_` Match this literally
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `\d+` Matches one or more digits
- `(?=_)` Positive lookahead asserting what follows is `_`

Answer (score 0):

use the [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) function:

```
$str = "ddw_01_fdfd";
preg_match('/.+_([0-9]+)_.+/', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Output:

```
01
```

Another way to do it is by explode the string by `_`:

```
$xpl = explode('_', $str);
$middleStr = $xpl[1];
```

The [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) function splits a string by string, in that case create an array made by all substring contained in `$str` dividing them by `_`.

Try it [here](https://eval.in/952692).